# How to extract stdout redirection in unittest code to make it safe reusable by other test cases?

Tags: python, unit-testing, redirect, inheritance, stdout

I want to test code that includes some print statements I unfortunately can't get rid of. My approach was to capture stdout during tests and perform assertions on the captured outputs. I wanted to extract this redirection code to make it usable by many test cases. For example a very simple function like this

```
# something.py

def function():
    print("something")
    return 42
```

would be tested like this

```
import io
import sys
import unittest
import something

# test_something.py

class RedirectTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.original_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.temporary_stdout = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = self.temporary_stdout

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stdout = self.original_stdout

    def assertOutputEqual(self, expected_output):
        self.temporary_stdout.seek(0)
        captured_output = self.temporary_stdout.read().strip()
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, captured_output)


class TestFunction(RedirectTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()

    def test_output(self):
        something.function()
        self.assertOutputEqual("something")

    def test_return(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, something.function())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I extracted the stdout redirection code in a base class, but i don't like calling the base classes `setUp` and `tearDown` methods in each test case implementation. Is there a better way to make this approach accessible to multiple test cases? Especially, is possible to automatically call the base classes setUp and tearDown to make the tests cleaner and safer? Any other suggestions for improving this testing approach are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201210/multiple_inheritance_is_hard.html) by Ned Betchelder covering a similar issue using a mixin class. I used this approach to restructure the tests. It divides the code into independent pieces and the `super()` calls are avoided in the actual test cases.

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Base test case."""

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        # do basic setup stuff here ...

    def tearDown(self):
        # do basic teardown stuff here ...
        super().tearDown()

    def assertOutputEqual(self, expected_output):
        self.temporary_stdout.seek(0)
        captured_output = self.temporary_stdout.read().strip()
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, captured_output)


class RedirectMixin(object):
    """Mixin class for redirecting stdout on setup and teardown."""

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.original_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.temporary_stdout = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = self.temporary_stdout

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stdout = self.original_stdout
        super().tearDown()


class TestFunction(RedirectMixin, BaseTestCase):
    """Actual test case using stdout redirection."""

    def test_output(self):
        something.function()
        self.assertOutputEqual("something")

    def test_return(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, something.function())
```